# Filterrific date format after submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I'm using Filterrific for a expensive query so I decide to disable the ajax auto-submit on changes.

I use `mm/dd/yy` format in my jQuery date-picker and make translation in my backend code. However, after I submit the query form and the page get reloaded, `yy-mm-dd` format date appears in the filterrific. I have to select the date again to get it to correct format.

Can filterrific return the date value in format other than the standard mysql date format?

Comment: I think you have to return value in `mm/dd/yy` format so that it could get bounded as is..

Comment: @PankajParkar You are right! I just realized that I changed the format of original input in-place in my scope.

Comment: Does that solved your problem??